# URL.Action gives view not found error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

What am I missing here? I thought I have done this by the book, yet I get the error:
The view 'GetMoreLists' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/items/GetMoreLists.aspx

I have Controller

```
ItemsController: Controller
public ActionResult Index {...}
public ActionResult GetMoreLists (string item) {...}
```

I have view `Index.cshtml`. In the view I do:

```
<li><a href="@Url.Action("GetMoreLicts", "Items", new {item=    "books"})">Books</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the second parameter from `"Index"` to `"Items"`

```
@Url.Action("GetMoreLists", "Items" ...
```

Your controller is named `ItemsController`, not `IndexController`. Your method is also named `GetMoreLists()` but your code has `"GetMoreLicts"` (I assume that's a typo?)

It also appears that you have not created a view named `GetMoreLists.cshtml` in the `/Views/Items` folder.

Comment: <li><a href="@Url.Action("GetMoreLicts", "Items", new {item=    "books"})">Books</a></li>     I am sorry for the typo. This exactly what I have.....Items, not index.   Replace Index with Items and it is not working

Comment: Sorry - don't understand your comment. Note also your method is named `GetMoreLists` but you had `GetMoreLicts` - was that just a typo?

Comment: No you do not have `Items` - your code clearly shows that the second parameter of the method is `Index`!

Comment: And have you actually created a view named `GetMoreLists.cshtml` in the `/Views/Items/` folder?

Comment: I hear you man. I was changing my code so I can post it...And I made a mistake. I have no reason to lie. I will give you the correct answer anyway. Here is the think. I am stepping through the code, I hit the action, when I do return to list is when I get the error, and I think here is my misunderstanding. My expectation is to go back to the calling view which is Index. Maybe the right question is, how do I return back to the Index view?

Comment: And Steve regardless of the outcome of this question, your answer will be marked as correct. Thanks for helping

Comment: here is my return statement:  return View(allItems.ToList());

Comment: Not sure  understand fully, but if your calling the `GetMoreLists ()` method and from that method you ant to redirect to the `Index()` view then it would be `return RedirectToAction("Index")` but that does not seem to make much sense. If `GetMoreLists()` is a GET method, why would you then redirect?. You should edit your question showing the code in the controller methods so I can understand what your really trying to do.

Comment: return View("Index",allItems.ToList()); I should have step through this earlier. It was so obviuos....Steve answered the origina question correctly. Thanks for pointing me the right wat Steve

Comment: The index loads default data and creats a drop down list. The drop down list changes the data on the page. So you het all items, and the a drop down of all items. and you selct an item and you get all the different types of that item.

Comment: OK, In that case your not going about this the right way. You should have one method only - `public ActionResult Index(string item)`. In the `Index` view, include a form with `FormMethod.Get` that includes the dropdownlist (with `name="item"`) and  a submit button. In the index method, if the value of `item` is null, display all items, other wise filter your collection based on the value of `item`. However, you will get much better performance if you were to use ajax to call a method that returns the filtered collection and save having to regenerate the whole view each time